# Else is printing nothing

Tags: java

I'm practicing to get bit better in this so I started with this.
The problem is that when I try to use the `else` to test, it doesn't print. The program ends there and that's it.
Does anyone know why?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CuentaBancaria
   {
       public static void main(String args[])
      {
         double EstatusDelBalance = 0.00, Balance = 0.00, Deposito = 0.00, Retiro = 0.00;
         Scanner vgd = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Tu balance actual es: 0");
         {
            if (EstatusDelBalance <= Balance)
            {
               System.out.println("\nCuanto desea depositar? ");
               Deposito = vgd.nextDouble();
               Balance = Deposito + Balance;
               System.out.println("\nCuanto desea retirar? ");
               Retiro = vgd.nextDouble();
               Balance =  Balance-Retiro;
               EstatusDelBalance = Balance;
            }
            else 
            {
               System.out.print("No hay balance suficiente para el retiro");
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: This `if (EstatusDelBalance <= Balance)` will always be true when you do `EstatusDelBalance = Balance;`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm not sure I understand your problem, it is workin as it should if it doesn't print the else part, because `EstatusDelBalance <= Balance` is always true in your code. Change `Balance` to something like `1.00` and it'll print the else part.

Comment: Can you please share the values by which you are trying to test else portion?

Comment: If you want to test your else, you can either change **EstatusDelBalance** to have a higher value than **Balance** or add a while section plus a quit option to exit the loop.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add information. Well what I'm trying to do is a program based on Bank accounts. I add money EstatusDelBalance save it and then (just testing this) I try to input more "money" than the one I have in the "account"(Blance) to activate the else and print ("sorry, you do not have enough balance to make that withdrawal")

Answer (score 3):

`EstatusDelBalance`  is `0.0`, `Balance` is `0.0`, so `EstatusDelBalance <= Balance` will always be true. You might want to use [`while loop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The else is never print because `EstatusDelBalance` = `Balance`. The else would be printed only when `EstatusDelBalance` > `Balance`.

But I suppose that you are missing something because you have extra `{}` that are unnecessary here (but would be necessary if you have a loop !)... at lines with '???'.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
        public class CuentaBancaria
       {
           public static void main(String args[])
          {
             double EstatusDelBalance = 0.00, Balance = 0.00, Deposito = 0.00, Retiro = 0.00;
             Scanner vgd = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Tu balance actual es: 0");
??? ->             {
                if (EstatusDelBalance <= Balance)
                {
                   System.out.println("\nCuanto desea depositar? ");
                   Deposito = vgd.nextDouble();
                   Balance = Deposito + Balance;
                   System.out.println("\nCuanto desea retirar? ");
                   Retiro = vgd.nextDouble();
                   Balance =  Balance-Retiro;
                   EstatusDelBalance = Balance;
                }
                else 
                {
                   System.out.print("No hay balance suficiente para el retiro");
                }
??? ->              }
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the thing is to make else block executable check out this.I think that's what you expected.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CuentaBancaria
    {
       public static void main(String args[])
      {
         double EstatusDelBalance = 0.00, Balance = 0.00, Deposito = 0.00, Retiro = 0.00;
         Scanner vgd = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Tu balance actual es: 0");
         System.out.println("\nCuanto desea depositar? ");
         {
             Deposito = vgd.nextDouble();
             Balance = Deposito + Balance;
             System.out.println("\nCuanto desea retirar? ");
             Retiro = vgd.nextDouble();
             Balance =  Balance-Retiro;
             if (EstatusDelBalance <= Balance)
             {
             EstatusDelBalance = Balance;
             }
             else 
             {
             System.out.print("No hay balance suficiente para el retiro");
             }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do thx a lot